# Unload as2 swf nested inside an as3 container

Tags: actionscript-3

What I'm trying is unload an as2's swf from and as3's swf containner. So It's running okay when loading the as2 swf from an as3 swf cointainner's button as you can see in the next code:

> //AS3 cointainner "AS3Loader_TEST1":

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("AS2animation_TEST1.swf"));
addChild(loader);
```

> // and for solving the pitfall, I tryed this:

```
   var AVM_lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection(); 

    loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopandback);
    function stopandback(event:MouseEvent):void {
     AVM_lc.send("AVM2toAVM1", "disappear");

   }
```

=======================================================

> //then, into the "AS2animation_TEST1.swf" it's written

```
  var AVM_lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    AVM_lc.dissapear = function(){
    animation_mc.unloadMovie();
  }

AVM_lc.connect("AVM2toAVM1");
```

So, the last script unload a movieclip nested in AS2animation_TEST1.swf at addEventListener dispatched from a mouse click into the as3 containner
but that's not the way I'm looking for. 
So, What do you figure out  to unload the whole AS2animation_TEST1.swf

Comment: If you put it on stage with `addChild(loader);` then later you can simply remove it with `removeChild(loader);`. Is that not working?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So as you're saying, It works anyway, but how to pass "removeChild(loader);" to a button inside the as2 swf.

Comment: I dont know about mixing code for AS2 and AS3 languages. They're different systems. Either try to override the AS2 button's click function (do you know what its called?) or else add your own AS3 close button positioned above the old AS2 one.